# How to set title for each object in Node Js JSON output?

Tags: node.js, json, retrofit2

When I fetch data from the database and send the result as JSON, My JSON output has objects without any name. I want to set a name for each object for parsing JSON in the android. How can I do this??? 
Or How can I parse this with Retrofit in android without object name?

my JSON file

```
[
    [
        {
            "Title": "title 1",
            "Id": 1,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Title": "title 2",
            "Id": 13,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Title": ""title 3",
            "Id": 14,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": "answer 1",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 2",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 3",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 4",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 5",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 6",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 7",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 8",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 9",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 10",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 11",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 12",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        }
    ]
]
```

And That's what I want

```
[
    "questions": [
        {
            "Title": "title 1",
            "Id": 1,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Title": "title 2",
            "Id": 13,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Title": ""title 3",
            "Id": 14,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        }
    ],
  "answers": [
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": "answer 1",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 2",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 3",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 4",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 5",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 6",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 7",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 8",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 9",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 10",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 11",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 12",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        }
    ]
]
```

and my node js code for fetch

```
router.get('/getquestion/:roomid/:subject/:count',async(req,resp,next)=>{
    (async function(){
        let pool = null;
        try{
            pool = await connection
            let result = await pool.request()
            .input('i_roomid',sql.BigInt,req.params.roomid)
            .input('i_subject',sql.BigInt,req.params.subject)
            .input('i_count',sql.Int,req.params.count)
            .query(`exec questproc @i_roomid,@i_subject,@i_count`)
            if(result){
                resp.status(200).send(result.recordsets).end;
            }
        }catch(err){
            console.log("Failed")
                resp.status(500).send(err).end;
        }

    })()
},closePoolMiddleware)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not store array in json file, store an object instead.
to have property names your json file should look like

```
{
    "questions": [
        {
            "Title": "title 1",
            "Id": 1,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Title": "title 2",
            "Id": 13,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Title": ""title 3",
            "Id": 14,
            "RoomsExams": 93
        }
    ],
    "answers":[
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": "answer 1",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 2",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 3",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 1,
            "Title": ""answer 4",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 5",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 6",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 7",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 13,
            "Title": ""answer 8",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 9",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 10",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": false,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 11",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        },
        {
            "Ok": true,
            "Questions": 14,
            "Title": ""answer 12",
            "RoomsExams": 93
        }
    ]
}
```